# Does Collections.shuffle guarantee the result is not sorted?

Tags: java, collections

Does `Collections.shuffle` guarantee the resulting list is not sorted in ascending or descending order?

Suppose I have a list of Strings `letters` containing "a", "b", "c", "d".

After `Collections.shuffle(letters)` will `letters` ever be equal to a-b-c-d or d-c-b-a?

If `letters` can end up ordered, is there a way to prevent `Collections.shuffle` from leaving the list sorted in ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it doesn't, because then it wouldn't be a random shuffle.  Just because those two permutations look ordered to us humans doesn't mean they should be avoided when selecting a random permutation.

If you do want to avoid ascending and descending order, you can shuffle in a loop checking whether the list is ordered.

```
while (isSorted(list) || isSorted(list, Comparator.reverseOrder())
    Collections.shuffle(list);
```

with an appropriate implementation of `isSorted`.  (Note that this will be an infinite loop for a 0 or 1 element list!)

Comment: [Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) _depends_ on ascending order being one possible random ordering.